# Can I use ListDeconvolve or any other functions to get the original kernel?

Tags: convolution

I have seen an example in the help document:
`data1 = {0., 0., 1., 2., 1., 2., 1., 0., 0., 0.};
ker = {1/3, 1/3, 1/3};
conv = ListConvolve[ker, data1, 2]`
my question is: Can I get the `ker` back from the known `data1` and `conv`.
The document use `deconv = ListDeconvolve[ker, conv, Method -> "RichardsonLucy"]` but `deconv` is not equal to `ker`

Comment: `ListDeconvolve` as you use it should produce you an approximation to `data1`. See, you have to provide the kernel `ker` to `ListConvolve`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this case, the following works just fine:

```
LeastSquares[
 Transpose@Through[{RotateLeft, Identity, RotateRight}[data1]],
 conv
 ]
```

> {0.333333, 0.333333, 0.333333}

More general with kernel length `2 k + 1`:

```
a = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 100];
k = 20;
ker = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 2 k + 1];
b = ListConvolve[ker, a, k + 1];


ker1 = LeastSquares[
   Transpose[RotateRight[a, #] & /@ Range[-k, k]],
   b
   ];

Max[Abs[ker - ker1]]
```

> 2.27596*10^-15

Comment: This is inverse methods as a one liner ! Nice !

Comment: Many thanks, chris!

Comment: Thanks ! you have provide a very good  idea

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 5):

This is a bit roundabout but one can treat this as a polynomial algebra problem. First pad both ends of data and convolution result with zeros so that the convolution emulates polynomial multiplication. Then do a division to get the kernel as a polynomial.

```
data1 = {0., 0., 1., 2., 1., 2., 1., 0., 0., 0.};
ker = {1/3, 1/3, 1/3};
conv = ListConvolve[ker, data1, 2];
```

Augment:

```
data2 = Join[{0.}, data1, {0.}];
conv2 = Join[{0., 0.}, conv, {0., 0.}];
```

Rewrite as explicit polynomials:

```
polyfactor = data2.x^Range[0, Length[data2] - 1];
polyprod = conv2.x^Range[0, Length[conv2] - 1];
```

Compute the kernel as coefficients of the polynomial quotient:

```
CoefficientList[Chop[PolynomialQuotient[polyprod, polyfactor, x]], x]

(* {0.333333333333, 0.333333333333, 0.333333333333} *)
```

If actual examples are large and efficiency is a concern, there are equivalent but faster ways to recover the kernel e.g. emulating the division using a Fourier transform.

Comment: It works...but really hard to understand.

Comment: There is a strong relationship between list convolution and polynomial multiplication.

Answer (score 4):

To approximate `ker` using [`ListDeconvolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListDeconvolve.html), use `data1` as the kernel.  Increasing [`MaxIterations`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxIterations.html) can improve the approximation.

```
data1 = {0., 0., 1., 2., 1., 2., 1., 0., 0., 0.};

ker = {1/3, 1/3, 1/3};

conv = ListConvolve[ker, data1, 2];

Column[ListDeconvolve[data1, conv, MaxIterations -> #, 
     Method -> "RichardsonLucy"][[5 ;; 7]] & /@ Range[10, 40, 10]]
```

[image]

Comment: your method looks very efficient. Can it work more general ,such as,when the convolution is not cycle?

Comment: I don't know. Suggest you experiment.